# Can't Include ContextMenu WIth jsp:include in ADF

Tags: java, jsp, oracle-adf

I am trying to include an ADF context menu via JSP include but the menu refuses to display. Here's the snippet of the  that attempts to include the menu:

```
<af:table value="#{mockupPersonController.people}"
    var="person" id="personDataTable"
    rowSelection="single" inlineStyle="width: 100%; height: 95%">
    <f:facet name="contextMenu">
        <af:popup id="tableContextMenu">
        <af:menu>
            <jsp:include page="/contextMenu.jsp" flush="true"/>
        </af:menu>
        </af:popup>
    </f:facet>
            ....
```

Here's part of the contextMenu.jsp. The idea is to use  to display various parts of the context menu based on the session scoped value of "whereami":

```
<af:commandMenuItem text="Review Person"
actionListener="#{personStatusBean.launchPopup}" />
<af:separator />
<af:switcher facetName="#{sessionScope.whereami}"
    defaultFacet="default">
<f:facet name="default">
    <af:commandMenuItem text="Main Menu" />
</f:facet>
<f:facet name="location1">
    <af:commandMenuItem text="Do Something" />
    <af:commandMenuItem text="Do Something Else" />
</f:facet>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a declarative component in order to do this...

Check this one out https://blogs.oracle.com/adffun/entry/fun_with_declarative_components

Answer (score 1):

Declarative menu is one way of doing this, the other way is to use a pagefragment and include it in a taskflow that you then bring into the page as a region.